# Pointer ownership with atomic variables

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, atomic

Does an atomic variable, 'containing' a pointer, take ownership of the pointer?

Consider the following snippet:

```
{
    std::atomic<Foo*> bar(new Foo());
}

// `bar' went out of scope, did it delete pointer to instance of Foo?
```

Of course I could derive and delete it myself, or work around it in another way; but that's not the point.

What is the **defined** behavior here, if any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the only thing `std::atomic` guarantees is that the object will be free from data races. So you will have free the memory that the pointer points to your self.

If you want a managed dynamic memory container, then either use a [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For completeness' sake, one (proper) way would be to: `delete bar.load(..)` before `bar` goes out of scope? I'm aware of 'smart' pointers, but I'd like a naked pointer here :-)

Comment: @pauluss86 That is fine, but if you do decide to do that way then you will have to enforce that no one uses the inner value of bar after it is been deleted.

Comment: In the real scenario it's a completely private member used only internally. I was just implementing the destructor of the encapsulating class, hence the question. I'll keep the question open for a few hours before picking an answer.

Answer (score 2):

No. `std::atomic<T*>` has a trivial destructor that does nothing, so it could not delete anything if it owned it.

`std::atomic<int>` doesn't "own" the integer, it just stores a value, and similarly `std::atomic<int*>` just stores a value, with no ownership or freeing implied.

Comment: when you perform `.store` on an atomic pointer does it store a pointer or does it store the pointee (ie where the pointer points to)?